# What does the .nv-l4t-disable-boot-fw-update-in-preinstall sentinel file do?

Tags: nvidia-jetson

When building a custom rootfs for NVIDIA Jetson devices, there are a few references online to touching the file `/opt/nvidia/l4t-packages/.nv-l4t-disable-boot-fw-update-in-preinstall`, but this file's purpose is not documented anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through the `nvidia-l4t-*` Debian packages included with the Linux for Tegra r32.7.2 board support package. Some of these packages include pre- and post-install scripts that reference the file:

1. `nvidia-l4t-init` creates files like `/etc/fstab` if the file does *not* exist.
2. `nvidia-l4t-initrd` skips flashing the new initrd if the file *does* exist.
3. `nvidia-l4t-core` does compatibility checks against `/proc` if the file *does not* exist.
4. `nvidia-l4t-xusb` skips flashing if the file *does* exist.
5. `nvidia-l4t-apt-source` inserts the correct SOC family name into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-l4t-apt-source.list` when the file *does not* exist.

In summary, the file mostly indicates whether you are installing a package on a live system or building a new rootfs where the host system is not the target Jetson device.